# identical md5 for JS and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, md5

for a small project I need identical md5 hashes for both JS and PHP.
Im using [this](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/instructions.html) javascript to convert a word to md5 (the .min version)

the word 'hello' outputs in

**JS**: ec59d44dee488759467970486fc9402d

**PHP**: 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

so they are not identical. I've tried to use `md5(utf8_encode($word));` instead of `md5($word);`

but both gave the same result.

Any ideas? Help is much appreciated

Comment: The PHP version is correct (I checked it with MySQL).

Comment: Don't understand your question. Are you creating two files (a PHP and a JS) of are you hashing the String only?

Comment: You're not using the same value in each. Paj's version and the PHP version both work correctly. So something is changing in the input value.

Comment: okay guys, the mistake was mine, I made a script that on keyup converted the word to md5, somehow I've let the script convert the md5 field... thanks guys. Still all these posts helped, PaulPRO post made me look closer and made me find the problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [md5](http://phpjs.org/functions/md5) function on [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/) gives the correct results.  It is dependent on [utf8_encode](http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_encode), so you need that as well.

Comment: The important detail here is the character encoding. MD5, like all hashes, works on the binary, which differs between the different encodings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate md5 value in Javascript, you may use this [md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) package

```
var md5 = require('md5');
console.log(md5('message'));
```

Then, use this [md5 online tool](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/hash/md5/?inputText=hello) to verify the result.